# Sanity fetch request workes only when call fetch 2 times with timeout

Tags: reactjs, sanity

when I make a delete or post request to sanity and fetching data again
it shows correct result only if I call fetch twice (or refresh page) and 2nd request should be with timeout

```
client.fetch(feedQuery).then((data) => {
    setPins(data);
    setLoading(false);
  });
  setTimeout(() => {
    client.fetch(feedQuery).then((data) => {
      setPins(data);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, 300)
```

Also I was trying to make a 1 request but with long delay 4000 it also not showing correct content in fact I already deleted item but it still there only on refresh page or call as first my option

```
import { createClient } from "@sanity/client";
export const client = createClient({
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  dataset: "production",
  apiVersion: "2023-06-05",
  useCdn: true,
  token: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_TOKEN,
});
```